# How to conditionally load and use components

Tags: reactjs

I have a folder called modules. Inside that folder there are some components. I want to conditionally load those components if their corresponding `.tsx` file exist. After many days trying to figure out how to do that without Node.js and only using React and ES6 features, I found the following solution by defining some flags:

```
let Foo;
if (flag === true) {
    Foo = lazy(() => import('./modules/foo.tsx'));
}

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            {flag ? <Foo /> : null}
        </>
    )
}
```

Now the problem is that the flag should be fetched from an API and I don't know how to use `lazy` with fetched data that indicate which module files exist.

Comment: The problem remains how you expect to know if the `.tsx` component is available in the folder without using node / php. You could try to load it within a `try catch` block and then catch the error if the component is not found? It's not a solid / reliable way of building an app though.

Comment: I know. My problem is some of those modules are paid extensions. So after building the react app, I want to remove those paid modules from dist folder but still want the app to be usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix that by using the lazy loaded component in a [`React.Suspense`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense):

```js
const Foo = React.lazy(() => import('./modules/foo.tsx'));

//...

  return (
    <div>
      ...

      {flag && (
        <React.Suspense>
          <Foo />
        </React.Suspense>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Like that the component's codebase will only be fetch once `flag` is true.

See this example for a demo:

[image: Edit react-suspense demo]

Comment: As I said the flag should be fetched from an API. How to do that?

Comment: @Dante Then just call the API within the component and use the result to determine `flag`. What's the painpoint there?

Comment: The problem is I get `importing non-existent modules` error if I import a component that does not exist.

Comment: If `flag` from the API is `false` it won't try to import it. Let the frontend have all the available modules/components and decide when to use them or not according to an external ressource => your API

Comment: I tried it now and you are right.

Answer (score 0):

- create your env file and add condition of them, something like below.

```js
let Foo;
if (process.env.REACT_APP_NODE_MODE === "premium-user") {
    Foo = lazy(() => import('./modules/foo.tsx'));
}

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            {process.env.REACT_APP_NODE_MODE ? <Foo /> : null}
        </>
    )
}
```